# Can SHAP values across different models in the same family of models trained on different datasets be aggregated?

Tags: forecasting, causality, shapley-value, explainable-ai

Let's say I have time - series data for 100 products in a particular store. I fit 100 regression models to generate 1-step forecasts for these products.

Let's say that all features are common across datasets, such as calendar and promotional events.

I compute SHAP values for such features and sum them up to find the aggregate impact of these features on my total forecasted demand for that particular store.

Is that a right way to calculate aggregate impact for each feature when the SHAP values are calculated for different datasets and models?

Comment: Shaply values generally compute what one feature adds to the rest, so if the set of other features differs, I'm not sure you'd get a meaningful result...

Comment: @Scriddie In the case when the set of features is the same across datasets, does adding them make sense?

Comment: Phew, good question! One would have to look at the formula to see if something like taking an average would be meaningful. I have never tried so I can't say, but it sounds more promising (or at least simpler) than the version with different features.

Comment: @Scriddie I haven't found anything in the existing literature arguring either for or against SHAP value aggregation to be honest.